# React Typescript Conversion issue rendering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise, race-condition

This is my first post!

I'm filtering through a list of products I'm fetching from Contentful using graphQL to find the product that matches what the user clicked. Everything worked before I converted the component to Typescript. I am vaguely familiar with TS and just started using it a few months ago.

When I log the product, I get back the Object with the correct filtered data, however when I go to access a key name "imagesCollection" I get the following TS error message:

> Property 'imagesCollection' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

If I `// @ts-ignore` the product image renders without issues. Is this a race condition of some kind?

[Typescript Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojFoS.png)

Any help is much appreciated as I have spent a good amount of time trying to solve it myself. Thank you!

The Component:

```
const Product = (props: any) => {
  // Custom HOOK for fetching Contentful Data
  const slug = props.match.params.slug;
  const { product } = useContentful(query, slug);
  console.log(product);
  const [jacketColor, setJacketColor] = useState(null);
  const [color, setColor] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setJacketColor(
      product.imagesCollection && product.imagesCollection.items[1].url
    );
    setColor(
      // @ts-ignore
      product.imagesCollection && product.imagesCollection.items[1].description
    );
  }, [product]);

  const changeColor = (jacketColor: string) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const filterHero = product.imagesCollection.items
      .filter((heroJacket: { title: string }) =>
        heroJacket.title.includes("hero")
      )
      .filter(
        (item: { description: string }) => item.description === jacketColor
      );

    setJacketColor(filterHero[0].url);
    setColor(filterHero[0].description);
  };

  const thumbnailImages = () => {
    return (
      // @ts-ignore
      product.imagesCollection &&
      // @ts-ignore
      product.imagesCollection.items
        .filter((jacket: queryProps) => jacket.title.includes("thumbnail"))
        .map((jacket: { url: string; description: string }, index: number) => {
          return (
            <img
              className={styles.thumbnailImages}
              key={`products-${index}`}
              src={jacket.url}
              // @ts-ignore
              alt={product.title}
              onClick={() => changeColor(jacket.description)}
            />
          );
        })
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {!product ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <div className={styles.productsContainer}>
          {/*  @ts-ignore */}
          <p className={styles.title}>{product && product.title}</p>
          {documentToReactComponents(
            // @ts-ignore
            product.description && product.description.json,
            RICHTEXT_OPTIONS
          )}
          {/*  @ts-ignore */}
          <p className={styles.price}>{`$${product && product.price}`}</p>
          {
            <img
              className={styles.productImage}
              //  @ts-ignore
              src={jacketColor}
              //  @ts-ignore
              alt={product && product.title}
            />
          }
          <p className={styles.selectColor}>{`Select a colour: ${color}`}</p>
          <div className={styles.thumbnailImagesWrapper}>
            {thumbnailImages()}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

The custom hook to fetch data:

```
function useContentful(query: string, slug: string | null) {  
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(graphqlURL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${REACT_APP_CDA_TOKEN}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({ data }) => {     
        if (slug) {
          data.arcteryxCollection.items.filter((item: queryProps) => {
            return item.slug === slug && setProduct(item);
          });           
        } else {
          setProducts(data.arcteryxCollection.items);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, [query, slug]);
  
  return { product, products };
}
```

The graphQL query structure:

```
export const query = ` 
query {
  arcteryxCollection {
    items {
      title
      slug
      description {
        json
      }
      price
      imagesCollection {
        items {
          url
          title
          description
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The TS interface I'm importing:

```
export interface queryProps {
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  price: number;
  description: {
    json: {
      content: {
        value: string;
      }[];
    };
  };
  imagesCollection: {
    items: {
      url: string;
      title: string;
      description: string;
    }[];
  };
}
```

Link to the Repo: https://github.com/danlubbers/arcteryx-graphql

Comment: It's best to include the full text of the error in the question itself, rather than linking to an external image. Generally you want to only link out to wholly auxiliary information, anything that's relevant should be included in the post itself. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 Otherwise, good first question :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are initializing your product state with an empty object.

`const [product, setProduct] = useState({});`

This makes TypeScript infer that your state's type is an empty object. Therefore, it doesn't have an `imagesCollection` on it.

You can either give it a type or initialize it with an object that has the properties you want.

Here is an example adding a type for your products. You can add the additional properties you need to use from the Graph QL response.

```
type ImageCollectionItem = {
    url: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
}

type ProductState = {
    imagesCollection?: {
        items: ImageCollectionItem[]
    }
}

//...

const [product, setProduct] = useState<ProductState>({});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read through and comment. I've not been able to figure out the solution with the provided code, but I do understand everything that you wrote. There may be something deeper than what is visible. Once I figure it out, I'll post my solution!

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I found that ended up working for me. In the use-contentful.ts hook I changed the way I filtered the response to store the data as an array instead of an object.

Seen here:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState<queryProps[]>([]);

          let filteredProduct = data.arcteryxCollection.items.filter((item: queryProps) => {                        
            return item.slug === slug;
          });          
          setProduct(filteredProduct);
```

This allowed me to then access the data in the Products Component and render it this way:

```
 const { product } = useContentful(query, slug);
 const productObj = product[0];

 const [jacketColor, setJacketColor] = useState("");

 setJacketColor(productObj && productObj.imagesCollection.items[1].url);
```